# CSS3 - Div width=100% pushes content to new line instead of using remaining space

Tags: html, css, width

I have looked around for a solution to this problem, but I haven't found anything that works.  This is a bit noobish so I apologize but I am a bit rusty in my CSS.

All I would like to do is to have 2 div elements aligned side by side horizontally that will take up 100% of the window's height and width.  The div on the left will have a fixed width value and the div on the right will take up the remaining space.

The solution is probably really simple and I am sure I am missing a basic concept to CSS which is causing this issue so if you could help me out and maybe point me to some literature to help me understand what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

[Fiddle Link to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/se3ja/)

The html code:

```
<div id="leftSideBar">Left Sidebar</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#leftSideBar{
    width:175px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#567880;
}
#content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00a0a0;
}
```

Comment: `width: 100%` means `100%` of the parent horizontally space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with floats instead:

```
#leftSideBar{
    width:175px;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    background-color:#567880;
}
#content{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00a0a0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution I was looking for.  I had tried floating the content but not the left side bar.  I will read up on floats to get a better understanding of how to use them properly =P

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you're missing `display:inline-block`. Div are block elements which means that by default they use up 100% of the container width regardless of the width you set. By setting them to inline-block you enable other elements to appear alongside them.

```
#leftSideBar
{
    width:175px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#567880;
    display:inline-block;
}
#content
{
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00a0a0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se3ja/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the number of answers provided, there are a few ways to accomplish this. One of the easiest is to wrap your divs in a container, and apply the background color to the new element. Float `#leftSideBar`, and your `#content` div will be positioned beside it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSideBar">Left Sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#00a0a0;
}
#leftSideBar{
    width:175px;
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#567880;
}
#content{
    height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWtkw/)

Answer (score 0):

By setting the content div to 100%, you're making it take up 100% of its container. If you want them to share, then you need to divvy up the percentage between them and use floats, i.e.:

```
#content{
width:75%;
height:100%;
background-color:#00a0a0;
float:left;}

#leftSideBar{
width:25%;
height:100%;
float: left;
background-color:#567880;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#leftSideBar{
    width:175px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#567880;
    float:left;
}
```